# tcpdump shows nothing for my C++ application?

Tags: c++, centos6, multicast, tcpdump, iperf

If I run:

```
iperf -s -u -B 224.0.31.155
```

and run

```
sudo tcpdump -ni any 'host 224.0.31.155'
```

tcpdump is able to capture something:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
15:49:15.334484 IP [some ip].14386 > 224.0.31.155.14386: UDP, length 1364
15:49:15.334728 IP [some ip].14386 > 224.0.31.155.14386: UDP, length 1374
15:49:15.375026 IP [some ip].14386 > 224.0.31.155.14386: UDP, length 1058
15:49:15.375184 IP [some ip].14386 > 224.0.31.155.14386: UDP, length 832
```

However, if I kill my iperf process above, and then start my C++ application that also joins the same group and binds the same port, tcpdump no longer sees the traffic.

Here is the snippet:

```
struct sockaddr_in mc_addr; /* socket address structure */
struct ip_mreq mc_req; /* multicast request structure */
unsigned int from_len = sizeof(mc_addr); /* source addr length */

/* construct a multicast address structure */
memset(&mc_addr, 0, from_len);
mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_aton(mcastGroup.c_str(), &mc_addr.sin_addr);
mc_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

/* bind to multicast address to socket */
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr)) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "failed to bind to the port " << port << "|error="
            << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    throw;
}
/* construct an IGMP join request structure */
mc_req.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mcastGroup.c_str());
mc_req.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

/* send an ADD MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
if ((setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void*) &mc_req,
        sizeof(mc_req))) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "failed to set socket option to request for membership"
            << std::endl;
    throw;
}
```

tcpdump details:

```
$ tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.1-PRE-CVS_2012_03_26
libpcap version 1.4.0
```

I just checked it on one of my production servers and it shows the same behavior but I see that my C++ application is processing data properly.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I'm not sure what `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` would do, but probably you also need to `listen`

Comment: I use epoll to monitor the file descriptor and so listen() isn't required.

Comment: You can capture data just by running "iperf -s -u -B 224.0.31.155"? It seems that you just start a server which is listening.Your code is to generate multicast traffic, it seems have different function from your iperf command. Can you give more details ?

Comment: "iperf -s -u" means "server mode" with UDP support.  It doesn't capture packet.  It just joins the multicast group so is my code -- it joins the multicast group without capturing.

Comment: @Hei you code works for me, as I add sleep for a while after your snippet, and produce some traffic from other node ```iperf -c 224.0.31.155 -u -T 32 -t 1 -i 1 -p 14386```, maybe you can add some code to read data after your snippet and see what you will get ?

Comment: @sel-fish yes, my C++ code above works in a sense that it does join the group and I am able to read the data from the socket.  Just that while I am reading data from the socket through my C++ code, tcpdump doesn't sniff anything.  That's the original question here.

Comment: @Hei In my case, tcpdump could sniff, but can only sniff the content you read, not as much as you can sniff when run 'iperf -s -u -B 224.0.31.155', maybe just one line or two will be printed on the screen.

Comment: maybe you weren't sniffing the actual traffic when not using iperf because I ran into a case awhile back that a router in the office was sending traffic to a mcast group my C++ could join, and that traffic wasn't what I expected...

Comment: @Hei When  I said that I only sniff one or two lines, that's because my previous code just read 64 bytes and exit. I double checked and pretty sure that what I sniffed was produced by 'iperf -c 224.0.31.155 -u -T 32 -t 1 -i 1 -p 14386'. I can show you the steps I took to get that if you need, btw, I'm using CentOS release 6.5 (Final)/iperf-2.0.5, and tcpdump version as same as yours.

Comment: @sel-fish argh, I think there was a confusion.  If I use iperf to publish data and tcpdump to sniff, it looks good (my C++ code above has no involvement).  If I don't use iperf but try to use my C++ code above to join (and add a bit more code to read), tcpdump sniffs nothing.

Comment: @Hei I knew the problem. My experiment goes that way : 1st, I ran ''iperf -s -u -B 224.0.31.155 -i 1 -p 14386" at nodeA, ran tcpdump as nodeA too, then ran "iperf -c 224.0.31.155 -u -T 32 -t 1 -i 1 -p 14386" to generate data from nodeB, then the tcpdump process sniff; 2nd, I shutdown iperf at nodeA, and run c++ application, keep the tcpdump process run at nodeA, run iperf to generate data again from nodeB, tcpdump still sniff data. I see no confusion here.

Comment: @Ajay No. This is multicast. UDP. Not TCP.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem in your code is that you bind your socket to the multicast address. This is not required and may cause all kinds of weird behaviors.

If you only want to *send* UDP packets you do not need to bind your socket at all. The OS will do it for you.

If you want to send and receive multicast traffic you most likely want to bind to INADDR_ANY on Linux. This is almost an idiom. `bind()` on UDP sockets has very non-intuitive semantics on Linux. The IP address just has a filtering role. It neither binds to the specified IP address, nor does it bind to the interface associated with that IP address.

Another odd thing is that you assign to `mc_req.imr_interface` which should not be a member of `ip_mreq`. I think this should read `mc_req.imr_address`, but of course if this compiles then I shall stay silent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I just wanted to receive mcast messages.  And yes, it complied fine.

Answer (score 0):

IGMP messages are conserved. If the host is already a member of the group, it won't send out a new IGMP membership report message when another application joins. If you're receiving multicasts, be happy.

Comment: I raised this question because once awhile I need to use tcpdump to diagnose issues on production.  Thanks.